# Hive CSV line delimiter configuration

Tags: csv, hive

When creating an external table on a CSV file using Hive,
you can either use the Hive-internal CSV Serde:

```
...
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '...'
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')
```

or the OpenCSV Serde:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "separatorChar" = " ", "quoteChar" = '"', "escapeChar" = "\\" )
```

My question is, if I have a CSV file like this:

```
foo,bar,hello\rworld\rbaz,1\n
foo,bar,bye\rworld\rbaz,2\n
foo,bar,hi\rworld\rbaz,3\n
foo,bar,goodbye\rworld\rbaz,4\n
```

How can I configure the line endings to be `\n` and to ignore `\r` - keeping it part of the fields?

---

**Edit:**

-> When attempting to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` the following error occurs:

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 3:20 LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now. Error encountered near token ''\r\n''
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LINES TERMINATED BY` in your `create table` statement as below:

```
...
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '...'
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Let me confirm if it works and I will come back and mark it as solved!

Comment: I'm sorry, but as straightforward as it may seem, Hive does not behave differently when using `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.

Comment: It should work, there are plenty of example of this, you can find one here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_create_table.htm , I tried this and its working for me.

Comment: I was able to observe two effects: First, even with `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`, Hive still treats `\r` as line delimiters, and same happens when just completely removing this line from the statement! Second, and that might be the most important one, Hive will actually fail a query that contains something else than `\n` in the statement. I am not the only one to encounter this, either. See [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11996) as reference. From these findings I conclude that that line is **currently completely nonfunctional** and will be ignored by the deserializer...

Comment: Can you try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`?

Comment: `org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 3:20 LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now. Error encountered near token ''\r\n''`